# Detect type of scanned document and normalize it to given size

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, detection, scanning

I'm trying to implement a program that will take a scanned (possibly rotated) document like an ID card, detect its type based on two or more image templates and normalize it (de-rotated it and resize so it matches the template). Everything will be scanned, so luckily perspective is not a problem.

I have already tried a number of approaches with no success:

- I tried using openCV's features2d to detect the template and findHomograpy to normalize it but it fails extremely often. If I take a template, change it a little bit (other data/photo on ID card), rotate ~40 degrees then it usually fails, no matter what configuration of descriptors detectors and matcher I use.
- Also tried this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/unpaper.1.html which is an de-rotate tool and then tried to do normal matching but unpaper doesn't work great with rotation angles greater than 20 deg.

If there's a ready solution it would be really great, a commercial library (preferably c/c++ or a command line tool) is also an option. I hate to admit that but I fail miserably when try to understand computer vision papers so liniking unfortunately won't help me.

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: What you want to for image registration is to locate paired control points in both images that will allow for the mathematical transform, which is exact. There can be no error there (well, there can, but OpenCV is pretty mature now). You need to find a way to locate the appropriate control points (non-collinear) AT THE SAME RELATIVE POSITIONS in both images. It is most likely this step that you are messing up, causing poor results.

Comment: A good way to do this would be to write out the simple function that generates the homogenous transform matrix given a two sets of points yourself. It is fairly simple math and google can get you that. After that, only you know the ID card's details, so pick three points in a triangle that are NOT color/brightness/etc dependent (eg corners of borders, logo features, etc) and perform the transform

Comment: Do you know any extra information about the documents you are looking at?  Are they rectangles?  If they are, do they always go in the same orientation?  You could try to rotate and maybe resize before comparing to the template.  Then there would be only 2 orientations to match against and you could just try both.  Images would be helpfull